# Process items sequentially in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

In a flat file we have this type of record:

ID, Operation, Data

Operations include D = Delete, U = Update, I = Insert

1, D, Test

The problem is they are sending the same ID in the file multiple times and the ID could be anywhere in the file:

For example:

1, D, Test

1000 records later....

1, I, Testing

6000 records later....

1, D, Testing

In our SSIS package, we have a conditional split which directs or splits the data flow depending on the operation, delets versus updates.  The problem in SSIS is that it is not sequential in its rows processing (which is a good thing for performance) and deletes may happen after an insert or vice versa, which results in incorrect data.

What's the best way to handle this?

Some ideas we have come up with:

Dump the file into a temp table and have the row ID of the file appended to the record, then cycle throught the records sequentially in SQL Server using a cursor (order by file line number).

Use the ForEach container and go through each record sequentially in SSIS

Sort the file by IDs and then take the "latest" update.

Break the multiple operations it separate files.  For example, if a record had three updates, OriginalFile would become File1, File2, File3 and then run the files in order through SSIS.

Not all the records are like this.  It seems there are giving us a transactional history of the record rather than the latest update.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From personal experience, I found loading transaction data into a temp table first before processing to be the most effective way to process transaction data from a flat file.  From there, it depends on how you want to keep historical transaction data. Personally, my company wants to see when the product is added, the last update made to the product, when it is finally sent, and when the product is received by the customer.  So, loading the transaction data to a temp table to grab specifically what they want works for me.